# HTML 5 Audio controls on-site not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am hoping someone is able to help with a problem I am having. The below code manages the audio player on a website I am developing. The idea is that the user can click a mute button to toggle sound on the website and if the user clicks on a specific link to leave the site, the sound should be muted if not already.

So the first part of the script below sets a global variable for the audio player (audio html5 tag) (audioPlayer) and the second part sets a global variable for the mute button the user can click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var muteAudio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');
```

Then if someone clicks the mute button, I update the inner html of the mute button to either say mute or play, depending on what status the button is on

```
ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Mute';
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Play' : 'Mute';
```

And then I update the html 5 audio embed method

```
    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    muteAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

The second part of the script sets a 3rd global variable for a external link (SHOP) that takes users to the e-commerce store. If the sound is on, it should get muted when the user leaves. If the sound is not on, this if statement should not execute

```
ctrl3 = document.getElementById('muter');

if (ctrl.innerHTML.indexOf('Mute') != -1) {
console.log('not-muted');  
ctrl3.onclick = function () {

  $("#audioControl").click(); 
  return false;
};
}
else {console.log('did nothing');}

</script>
```

Problem is that the if statement does not appear to work. If the audio is muted, it should not execute the click function on the mute button to mute the sound when a user exits to the online store. What is happening is that the if statement always seems to be true because regardless of whether the mute button is in play state (i.e. the mute button says mute/inner html), it will toggle the sound to off if the music is playing and toggle the sound to on if the music is off (seemingly ignoring the if statements check of the inner html text.

You can see it live here http://goo.gl/DJMJBx

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to control pause/play or mute/unmute? The two seem to be confused.

Comment: Hi there. I am ultimately controlling the pause/play method for the audio embed. The Mute/Play is the text/inner html that the user sees in the button.

Comment: OK, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ctrl3's click handler is attached *conditionally*.

What you want is to attach the handler *unconditionally*, and perform the test inside the handler - ie whenever the link is clicked.

Here's the whole thing reworked to use jQuery throughout.

```
$(function() {
    var $audio = $('#audioPlayer'),
        $audioControl = $('#audioControl');

    $audioControl.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pause = $audioControl.html() === 'Mute';
        $audioControl.html(pause ? 'Play' : 'Mute');
        $audio.get(0)[pause ? 'pause' : 'play']();
    });

    $('#muter').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($audioControl.html() === 'Mute') {
            $audioControl.click(); 
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi there Roamer, thank you for your time and effort in helping me to resolve this problem. I attempted the above script on the site (it is now live) however if the audio is muted and you click the 'shop' link, the audio still unmutes itself (which was the original problem).

Comment: Actually, on reload of the site for a second visit (i think I was still getting a cache of my old script), the script does not work (undefined is not a function on line $audio[pause ? 'pause' : 'play']();

Comment: Okay, so it seems there was a missing ) on the last line which Ive added. Also, thinking that perhaps the #audioPlayer had not loaded yet (which is a common cause for this console error) I changed the code to be on document load, but to no avail

Comment: IQ, yes there was definitely a missing ')'. I also forget to unwrap the jQuery object before issuing the play/pause command. Edited above - give it another try.

Comment: Hi Roamer, it works perfectly now. Thank you again for your time and effort, it is greatly appreciated. Regards, IQ